# Is there a website allowing to see arrivals and departures at a specific airport on a specific date months in advance?

Tags: air-travel, airports, airlines, flight-search-engines

There are many websites showing arrivals and departures at a specific airport, but they only show at most a few days in advance from now. Is there any website to show flight even a month or two from now?

I don't need to know the gate or anything like that, just what flights are going, as so to explore options for travel planning if I want to arrive at a specific airport in a specific time range.

The ability to filter by current cost of a ticket for that flight, and the region of the departure/destination city (eg. continent/sub-continent/country) would be a big bonus.

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but you will find useful answers at this question I asked a while ago: [Flight Search from anywhere to a specific destination](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/73709/32134)

Comment: Related https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/102535/how-can-i-find-the-time-schedule-of-flights-to-from-a-given-airport

Answer (score 1):

The only reliable place you would find this information is in airline's specific schedules - which are published well in advance for their routes.

Here is an [example for Emirates (large pdf)](https://cdn.ek.aero/downloads/ek/pdfs/timetables/Emirates-Schedule-29-Oct-2017-24-Mar-2018.pdf) which is for 29-Oct-2017 till 24-Mar-2018, after which the airline will publish an updated schedule.

These flights may, of course, be subject to cancellations.

cleartrip offers an [online version](https://www.cleartrip.sa/flight-booking/emirates-airlines.html) of this same timetable that may be handy.

Comment: What I am looking is a website listing these by airport and date, not by airline. There are hundreds of websites listing flights by from to and date, so there is no reason some of them couldn't list them by departure or destination airport by date.

Answer (score 1):

You can search on [Skyscanner](http://www.skyscanner.net) for flights from a specific airport or city to "Everywhere" on a particular date, and the results are grouped by country and sorted by (estimated) prices.

Although it doesn't seem to permit "from everywhere to a specific airport", you can search for a round trip which comes back on the day you want to leave.